# Erro ao executar programa java para impressão através do PHP

Tags: php, java, html

Eu tenho uma aplicação web que gera uma imagem para um crachá e para conseguir enviar automaticamente para impressão, eu criei um programa em java que faz isso.

O programa roda perfeito, gerei um jar, colei junto com os arquivos do php dentro da www do WAMP, quando abro o cmd, navego até esta pasta e executo o seguinte...

```
java -jar crachaPrinter.jar imagem.png
```

O programa java executa perfeitamente e manda para impressão, tudo ocorre certinho...

Mas quando coloco em meu script php a seguinte linha...

```
exec("java -jar crachaPrinter.jar imagem.png");
```

O programa em java retorna o seguinte erro:

> Abr 01, 2014 4:26:27 PM crachaprinter.CrachaPrinter main Grave: null java.awt.print.PrinterException: No print service found. at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(Unknown Source) at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(Unknown Source) at crachaprinter.CrachaPrinter.main(CrachaPrinter.java:49)

A pedidos, trecho do código onde o erro é chamado:

```
try {
        printJob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CrachaPrinter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Não entendo porque o mesmo arquivo .jar encontra um serviço de impressão quando executado diretamente no cmd e não quando chamo a função pelo exec do PHP, o que pode ser feito?

Preciso que quando a página gera a imagem, ela chame este script para enviar automaticamente para impressão, essa foi a maneira que encontrei já que o PHP não faz isso nativamente atualmente, já utilizei o exec() para executar programas desta forma, mas nunca tive este tipo de problema.

Comment: o que tem na linha 49 do CrachaPrinter.java?

Comment: É o try que executa a função para executar o PronterJob

Comment: poderia editar sua pergunta adicionando esse trecho de código do try?

Comment: Quando você abre o CMD, você executa o jar como um usuário do SO. O apache está sendo executado com esse mesmo usuário? Checou se poderia ser problema de permissões de acesso do próprio SO?

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti Não chequei nada neste sentido, vou dar uma olhada no que eu conseguir sobre isso e dou um retorno. Preciso fazer isso funcionar para ontem haha :(

Comment: Qual SO esta utilizando? O objetivo é imprimir em uma impressora conectada no servidor ou no cliente? Qual o tipo da impressora (USB, Paralela, Serial, utiliza driver nativo, ou precisa de um driver legado)? Já escrevi diversos aplicativos fazendo dobradinha PHP+Impressora e cada cenário tem os seus pormenores... responda essas perguntas, talvez eu consiga ajudar.

Comment: Amigo, você poderia colocar o código java da impressão?

Comment: Bah mestre, já não tenho mais este código faz muito tempo, desculpe.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de utilizar o `exec()` que pode gerar uma falha de segurança no seu código, não é melhor com o PHP redirecionar para uma página que contenha a imagem e utilizar o método `window.print()` do javascript para poder fazer a impressão da mesma?

```
$imagem = //obter imagem;
```

```hmtl
<img src="$imagem.path" />
<script language="text/javascript">
  window.print()
</script>
```

PS: Claro que vc não precisa fazer tudo na mesma página nem com o JS embutido no HTML e etc, eu quis apenas dar um exemplo curto de como você poderia fazer..

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser besteira mais sera que esse erro não nasce do fato de o arquivo que você esta querendo criar esta fora do computador do servidor?

Se esse for o problema crie um pasta temporária de arquivos dentro do servidor nela conterá os arquivos que serão enviados para o cliente, faça um código que foce o download do arquivo pelo lado do cliente depois que terminar o download do arquivo, você deleta o mesmo.
Caso não queira ariscar falhas na função de deletar o arquivo pode programar para deletar ele de qualquer maneira em uma determinada hora